# ANOVA model usability, variances are unequal.

Tags: statistics

I have the following data:

[image]

It's about chickens laying eggs depending on what they are fed, and how they are fed it. I want to use ANOVA for analysing this, but the assumption of equality of variances is not met here. Is there any thing I can do in this case? Any sort of transformation I can apply that would allow me to use ANOVA?

Comment: When you say equality of variance are you saying homoscedasticity?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't know the english term

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/91872/alternatives-to-one-way-anova-for-heteroskedastic-data check that out and see if it helps

Comment: Yesterday I commented that a certain question posted here would fit equally well here or in stats.stackexchange.com.  But this one I think might get a better response there than here.